# where is timeIntervalSince1970 property in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get the current milliseconds and according to all the questions on Google, i should use timeIntervalSince1970 property of NSDate

however i already did this:

```
var startTime = NSData()
and then
startTime. timeIntervalSince1970

and
startTime. timeIntervalSince1970()
```

but it seems there is no property anymore, right?

if yes, what is the replacement please?

Comment: Why is that a space after the "."?

Comment: that is in the questions, just a type my friend,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is: `NSDate` not `NSData`.
Also there should not be space after the "."?

var startTime = NSDate()
let interval = startTime.timeIntervalSince1970

From Apple docs:

```
var timeIntervalSince1970: NSTimeInterval { get }
```

> This property’s value is negative if the date object is earlier than January 1, 1970 at 12:00 a.m. GMT.

Comment: omg, i used NSData instead of NSDate, how stupid i am. thank u

Comment: bty could you give me the documentation you talked about?

Comment: Select `timeIntervalSince1970 `  and  right-click and select "Jump to Definition. For documentation I use the Mac [Dash](https://kapeli.com/dash) app, it presents the Apple documentation in a very usavble manner.